# mysql query on joins using order by DESC

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT a.id, b.title, b.identifier,c.rating 
FROM mdl_course_modules a 
    LEFT JOIN mdl_scorm_scoes b 
        ON a.instance = b.scorm 
    and b.scormtype = ''
    LEFT JOIN training_rating C 
    ON C.training_id = a.id  
    and c.user_id = '1'
WHERE a.module='18'
ORDER BY rating DESC

error in : #1054 - Unknown column 'c.rating' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Can you share the DDLs of your tables?

Comment: is there `rating` column in training_rating table?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87f41/1 But in my local getting some error like : #1054 - Unknown column 'c.rating' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You alias `traning_rating` as `C` but you refer it as `c`(lowercase), that is the cause of the error. Please try this:

```
SELECT a.id, b.title, b.identifier,c.rating 
FROM mdl_course_modules a 
    LEFT JOIN mdl_scorm_scoes b 
    ON a.instance = b.scorm and b.scormtype = ''
    LEFT JOIN training_rating c
    ON c.training_id = a.id and c.user_id = '1'
WHERE a.module='18'
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Comment: You alias traning_rating as C(uppercase) but you refer it as c(lowercase), that is the cause of the error.

Comment: Unquoted identifiers like `c` and `C` are required to be the same thing by the SQL standard. I didn't know MySQL failed in such simple cases to stick to the standard.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're right, but it's mysql. Mysql is not very standard compliant.

Comment: Do you wnow which combination of configuration options cause this bug? Because the SQLFiddle example in the comments to the question works the way it is expected and on my local system it works as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. This http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html may answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that this stupid behaviour also applied to a table alias, not just to regular tables.